# Updating birtruntime to 4.4.1 maven gives following error

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.emf:jar:2.6.0.v20140901-1055
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.osgi:jar:3.10.1.v20140909-1633
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change:jar:
2.10.0.v20140901-1043
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.core.resources:jar:
3.9.1.v20140825-1431
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.emf.ecore:jar:2.10.1.v20140901-1043
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi:jar:
2.10.1.v20140901-1043
- Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt.runtime:org.eclipse.emf.common:jar:
2.10.1.v20140901-1043

How to install this file manually as I have downloaded the jar of this files but how to add in maven repositories.???

Answer (score 0):

They have a bug raised for this
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445642

You can also try this pom to include the dependencies manually

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/4.4.1/pom<sup>broken link</sup>